# Restrict array values in generic Record from containing the same value as the key its assigned to?

Tags: javascript, typescript, typescript-generics

I'm implementing a simple state machine. The config looks like this:

```
type StateMachineConfig<State extends string, TransitionState extends State> = Record<State, TransitionState[]>;
```

Each key should be a string enum.

And each value should be an array of the same string enums, **however the State that is given as a key should not be included in the array**

So given the following states:

```
enum MyStates {
    State1 = "State 1",
    State2 = "State 2",
    State3 = "State 3"
}
```

...the following should work:

```
const config: StateMachineConfig<MyStates, MyStates> = {
    [MyStates.State1]: [MyStates.State2],
    [MyStates.State2]: [MyStates.State3],
    [MyStates.State3]: [MyStates.State1, MyStates.State2]
}
```

...but not the following:

```
const config: StateMachineConfig<MyStates, MyStates> = {
    [MyStates.State1]: [MyStates.State2],
    [MyStates.State2]: [MyStates.State3],
    [MyStates.State3]: [MyStates.State2, MyStates.State3] // error: value in array is same as key
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a mapped type and `Exclude` for this:

```
type StateMachineConfig<State extends string, TransitionState extends State> = {
  [state in State]: Exclude<TransitionState, state>[];
};
```

<sup>([online demo](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play#code/C4TwDgpgBAysCGwIFl4GMAWBLAdhAwgPY4BmWA5gDxyLQQAeSOAJgM5SvABOu5ANFAAqXeDlZZgWYjSRQGTNrARIAfFAC8UAN4AoKFADanWlFxLaAXQBcUAKL00AGwCuzCJWGjxk6cogDjVQMLAG4dAF8wnQgcZwBbKGQQGQh2XX19FIBGDSgAIhSoLLy+PQyUgCZcgr8oCpKyzL8AZmrC5ryInTRiTige0gosmxTUTFwCYjIqJJTWAVm-VjVNdIyDRdpWADps60NNpB3Ki1KMg+Sl3b8K-Y3LrevaZtPGi7mnpBebe4-shYeR0+EFuXQGfQG0wqIz8Y2weCIgxmgNSALmK20b1+Vz2P0OqWBtzO63xxxud1JwJexP02MeKW+7xxNzRzOeFigAHpOXIuFxCFwbAA3eAuaBmeB8+AgUzsVjwOLQeDsADWEBAESAA))</sup>

Comment: This is great, thanks. One little hitch. If I generate a config, I can't do an `includes()` check on the array given a particular state. Do you know if this is surmountable without casting the array to State[]? See ts playground here: https://tsplay.dev/WJpprN

Comment: @ShaneCallanan I can't think of anything that would make TypeScript infer this correctly, a type assertion is probably necessary